# Save to an ArrayList of a model object

Tags: arraylist, playframework-2.0

I am using Play Framework 2.0.4 and in my model class one of the variables is an `Array List<Long>` datatype, declared here:

```java
public List<Long> associateBooks = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

I have a view template that invokes a controller method with two Long values that represent the id's of two different objects of the same model type.

```
GET     /addAssociate/:oID/:id              controllers.Application.addAssociate(oID: Long, id: Long)
```

The controller method invoked:

```java
public static Result addAssociate(Long oID, Long id) {

    Book.addAssociate(oID, id);
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}
```

I know the controller method is performing its action because I get redirected to the index page and I know it receives the values because the URL changes as expected.

The problem lies in the Book model method addAssociate shown below.

```java
public static void addAssociate(Long oID, Long match) {

    List<Book> allBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
    allBooks = find.all();

    for(Book book: allBooks) {

        if(book.id == oID) {
            book.associateBooks.add(match);
            book.save();
        }
    }
}
```

In this method I want to go through all book objects and if the id matches the value of the variable `oID` passed from the view to the controller I want to add the value of match (the other arguement) to the `associateBooks` list (of type `Long`) that belongs to each journey object. I then try and save the changes to the object being considered during this iteration. The problem is the list `associateBooks` still seems to be **empty** when I print it out on other view templates.

Update: Even if I remove the condition it still doesn't add anything to the list.

Comment: Do you want to save your `associateBooks` lists on the database?

Comment: Yes I want the list to be a property of the Book objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save your list of associated books, maybe you would like to follow this:

> **NOTE:** I suggest to create additional table named `book_associated`. It look like this
>
> ```
> +--------+-------------------+
> |book_id |associated_book_id |
> +--------+-------------------+
> |1       |2                  |
> |1       |3                  |
> +--------+-------------------+
> ```
>
> It means that book with ID `1` associated with book with ID `2` and `3`
>
> But, this has a **disadvantages** if `Book 1` is associated with `Book 2` we cannot determine if `Book 2` is also associated with `Book 1` because it didn't declared on the table.

So on your model should look like below:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    // other fields
    ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="book_associated",
        joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="associated_book_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    )
    public List<Book> associateBooks = new ArrayList<>();

    // other methods and finder
    ...

}
```

Here you can save all your list of associated book of any book. This is for your reference about Many-to-Many relation on java :

1. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany
2. http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/ManyToMany

Comment: Will do this require making a new model class for book associated?

Comment: Of course, yes. But if you are on DEVELOPMENT mode, the EVOLUTIONS script will automatically build this table. You may tried that friend!